# How can I tell what options are in use on a running Mosquitto Service

Tags: mosquitto

How can I tell if the settings files associated with a Mosquitto instance, have been properly applied?

I want to add a configuration file to the `conf.d` folder to override some settings in the default file, but I do not know how to check they have been applied correctly once the Broker is running.

i.e. change persistence to false (without editing the standard file).

Answer (score 0):

Test it.

You can run mosquitto with verbose output enabled, which will generally give you feedback on what options were set, but don't just believe that.

To do that, stop running Mosquitto as a service (how you do this depends on you setup) and manually run it from the shell with the `-v` option. Be sure to point it at the correct configuration file with the `-c` option.

That's not enough to be sure that it's actually working properly. To do that you need to test it.

Options have consequences or we wouldn't use them.

If you configure Mosquitto to listen on a specific port, test it by trying to connect to that port.

If you configure Mosquitto to require secure connections on a port, test it by trying to connect to the port unsecured (this shouldn't work) and secured (this should work).

You should be able to devise relatively simple tests for any options you can set in the configuration file. If you care if it's actually working, don't just take it on faith; test it.

For extra credit you can bundle the tests up into a script so that you can run an entire test suite easily in the future and test your Mosquitto installation anytime you make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Having duplicate configuration options with different values is a **REALLY** bad idea.

The behaviour of mosquitto is not defined in this case, which value should be honoured, the first found, the last? When using the `conf.d` directory, what order will the files be loaded in?

Also will you always remember that you have changed the value in a `conf.d` file in the future when you go looking?

If you want to change one of the defaults in the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` file then edit that file. (Any sensible package management system will notice the file has been changed and ask what to do at the point of upgrade)

The `conf.d/` directory is intended for adding extra listeners.

Also be aware that there really isn't a default configuration file, you must always specify a configuration file with the `-c` command line option. The file at `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` just happens to be the config file that is passed when mosquitto is started as a service when installed using most Linux package managers. (The default Fedora install doesn't even setup the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` directory)